# Any .NET library to calculate polygon area?

Tags: .net, geometry

Is there a .NET library to calculate area enclosed by polygon made up of geo coordinates (lat longs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/93087#1376725) has a polygon class with an Area method. But before calling that, you should consider *projecting* the polygon's coordinates into an [equal area projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equal-area) to yield meaningful results.  It looks like SharpMap uses [ProjNet](http://projnet.codeplex.com/), which has Albers, but I also see there is now a [c# wrapper](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/C-NET-wrapper-updated-td4495444.html)  for [Proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/).

Comment: Also, take a look at DotSpatial. https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial

Answer (score 11):

NetTopologySuite offer what you need, and much more:
http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/

Comment: +1  I'd forgotten about nettopologysuite, looks like it has a lot more momentum than SharpMap.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types library.  While it isn't supplied in .NET, it is available as a nuget package, or you can find it in your SqlServer (or Express) installation (%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies) as Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

Obviously, it relies on Microsoft (and the SQL types library which could have it's own licencing issues), so the other options supplied may well be better options, but if you are already integrating with SqlServer 2008, then this may be a nice way to go.

To do an area calculation is pretty simple (I have included an NUnit test below demonstrating it.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    class GeometryTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void CheckAreaTest()
        {
            string polygon = "POLYGON((145 -42 , 147 -42, 147 -40, 145 -40, 145 -42))"; //wkt string over Tasmania, Australia
            SqlGeography geom = new SqlGeography();
            SqlChars geometryString = new SqlChars(new SqlString(polygon));
            geom = SqlGeography.STPolyFromText(geometryString, 4326);
            Assert.AreEqual(37371149986.1, Math.Round(geom.STArea().Value, 1));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: While your example helps achieve find the area but it doesn't address the part where I said that I have lat, longs because area needs to be calculated in meters.

Comment: By using SqlGeography, the STArea is automatically in square metres (which is why it is so big).  Will ammend to give better values in the string polygon string to avoid confusion.

Comment: Try the following that maps approximately to utah's boundary..You will get a value 509850820193573 that's about the size of the Earth's surface area: "POLYGON((-114.1142489 37.12741587,-114.0703035 41.87154978,-111.0380770 42.10020423,-110.9501864 41.08136450,-109.1484285 40.98191446,-109.1044832 37.12741587,-109.1044832 37.0573086,-114.1142489 37.12741587))"

Answer (score 0):

Link to System.Data.Entity.dll and use the DbGeography object such as:

```
DbGeography geography = DbGeography.FromText(wktString);
double? myArea = geography.Area;
```

Comment: Welcome! Expanding on your answer may be helpful for the original poster and any future people who find this post in the future.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer